# what does 革去功名 mean?

Tags: vocabulary, listening

I am watching 天下一碗 , in this [link](https://youtu.be/e-5zMV8AsH8?t=1954), ChengXi says that his friend HuaQiang 革去功名

Does it mean that he got famous in a revolution or reformist group? as he got involved in a political movement? and that he will always be in trouble?

Or does it mean he lost his honor and name? and became considered a traitor?

I searched but did not find any explanation online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/1072/
>
> 革: [3] [v] get rid of; dismiss; abolish

革 = remove (verb)

去 = away (result complement)

[功名](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/57657/) = scholarly honour plus official position (noun)

革去功名 means "strip away all titles and government positions

Comment: thanks so much Tang Ho , so that's what it means ... I just learned a new vocabulary, best ! +1

Answer (score 1):

It means something akin to "remove his rank/honor".

Comment: Thank you so much, I looked futher and think it is a concept that belongs to confucianism : https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%9D%A9%E5%8E%BB isn't it?